# How do I try out GHC 7.8-RC1 with projects requiring libraries?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I've downloaded the binary distribution for GHC 7.8-RC1. It did a nice job installing separate ghc/ghci/ghc-pkg binaries for 7.6 and 7.8. I can launch ghci and do wonderful things, and I can compile simple hello world files, but if I try to do anything that uses any libraries, etc it doesn't find them (unsurprisingly).

I've done some googling and it doesn't seem obvious how I would go about messing with larger projects compiled with 7.8, and even more strangely I don't find others asking the question. Maybe I've missed something obvious? I'm a Haskell noob, but there are some things that require 7.8 that I'm keen to experiment with.

I'm running OS X Mavericks with Xcode 5 which I understand causes some trouble, but I've worked around the things so far by installing gcc 4.8 and referencing it as necessary.

Comment: Which libraries are you trying to use?

Comment: Well there are a number of things I'd like to experiment with. I want to try lamdu which is broken w/ 7.6 on OS X, but there's a branch that adds support for 7.7. It has a number of dependencies. I'd also like to experiment w/ the iOS stuff for which I'm not sure which libraries I'll need, and I've been messing w/ some gtk stuff that would be fun to use w/ 7.8 features. I tired to keep the Q more general as I would hope there would be a way to basically set up a separate cabal environment or something as long as the pkg was compatible.

Comment: Also try brew install --devel ghc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you just set your `PATH` to pick up the ghc78 binaries you can just use `cabal` (from an existing Haskell Platform install.)

`cabal` already segregates packages by ghc version, so it won't use any packages built with older versions of ghc.

For iOS, see this post for a build of ghc rc1:

http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/ghc-devs/2014-February/004004.html

Here is what is working for me. I am using Lion, but the same process should work under Mavericks.

```
cd /tmp
wget http://www.haskell.org/ghc/dist/7.8.1-rc1/ghc-7.8.20140130-x86_64-apple-darwin-lion.tar.bz2
tar jxf ghc-7.8.20140130-x86_64-apple-darwin-lion.tar.bz2
cd ghc-7.8.20140130
mkdir $HOME/ghc78
./configure --prefix=$HOME/ghc78
make install

export PATH="$HOME/ghc78:$PATH"
cabal update
cabal install dimensional-tf-0.3
```

This test the new negative literal syntax (see [this recent blog post](http://flygdynamikern.blogspot.com/2014/02/joy-and-caution-with-xnegativeliterals.html))

```
$ ghci -XNegativeLiterals
GHCi, version 7.8.20140130: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> import Numeric.Units.Dimensional.TF.Prelude
...> -123.56 *~ kilo meter
Loading ...
...
Loading package numtype-tf-0.1.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package dimensional-tf-0.3 ... linking ... done.
-123560.0 m
```

Comment: Okay great, I think that's exactly what I was looking for. Also wow negative literals, hadn't seen that! nice! I'll give 'er a go and make the check green if it works :).

Comment: You do not have to mess with `PATH`, just pass `--with-compiler ..../ghc-7.8.1` to `cabal install`.